# Advice for printing a colored page

Tags: printer, printing, colors

If I need to print a colored document on a black and white printer, then which one of these options do you think is better:

1. desaturating the document first and then sending it to printer
2. giving the print command on the colored document only (trusting the printer for the job)

I know most of us use the second option. I want to know if there is any possible advantage of using the first option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting printer handle color conversions is right thing to do. All modern printers know how to do it correctly.

Only if you have older printer (here I am thinking of 5 years and older) you will get any improvement with manual desaturization.

Comment: I'd go with 10 years or older ... I print every day on a 5 year old Canon; no problems whatsoever.